# ToString() overload not being called after linq query

Tags: c#, tostring

**Update:** The problem still exists in my real world solution - not in LinqPad though. I understand you cannot reproduce it. I cannot either. As soon as I have some spare time at my disposal I will strip down the real world solution to be able to share it.

Consider this simple class

```
public class Node
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("This is the Node.ToString() method!");
    }
}
```

I have two linq queries. Both of them return exactly the same result with the difference being the later query groups on a previously sorted list.

```
// working example
var query = unsortedNodes.GroupBy(n => n.Group).SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(n => n.SequenceNumber));
_nodes = query.ToList();
_nodes.ForEach(n => LoggerProxy.Debug(_logger, null, "Node {0}", n));
```

**Example result:**

```
2015-12-21 15:29:00.9083  DEBUG   Company.Project.Controls.MyControl   Node "This is the Node.ToString() method!"
```

**Good!**

However if I add another "orderby" to the linq query, because I also want the grouping to be sorted, the ToString() method suddently does not work anymore.

```
// query working, but ToString() in logger method is not.
// sort by group, group by group, sort by sequence number
var query = unsortedNodes.OrderBy(n => n.Group).GroupBy(n => n.Group).SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(n => n.SequenceNumber));
_nodes = query.ToList();
_nodes.ForEach(n => LoggerProxy.Debug(_logger, null, "Node {0}", n));
```

To my surprise the logs only show the class name (default ToString() behavior) now.

**Example result:**

```
2015-12-21 15:25:00.0137  DEBUG   Company.Project.Controls.MyControl   Node "Company.Project.Node"
```

**BAD!**

**It's not about the logger. Visual Studio intermediate window:**

```
_nodes[0].ToString();
"Company.Project.Node"
((QpVisualizerNode)_nodes[0]).ToString();
"Company.Project.Node"
```

.NET framework version is 4.5.51209 (release 379893)

The issue is reproducable both ways by adding and removing the ".OrderBy(n => n.Group)" statement in the linq query.

Any clue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using a simple console app and Console.Writeline. Can you try doing a Build -> Clean, rebuild and confirm that it is still an issue?

Comment: Please, give us more details. Which logger do you use or it's custom.

Comment: With Console.WriteLine works fine

Comment: Curious, if you change the `LoggerProxy.Debug` statement to a `Debug.WriteLine`, what do you get?

Comment: Expand your logger to include the type of `n`, that may be all the info you need.  Ex: `_nodes.ForEach(n => LoggerProxy.Debug(_logger, null, "Node {0} of type {1}", n, n.GetType().Name));`

Comment: I suspect that you are referencing an intermediate object added by the Linq statements.  For Example, `GroupBy` gives an IEnumerable of `IGrouping`, which in turn is IEnumerable of your type.

Comment: It's not about the logger. Console.WriteLine shows the exact same behavior. I even tried casting the object to my Node type and calling ToString returned the default output.

Comment: I and others are not getting the same behavior using `Console.WriteLine`. Can you update the question with a full example that we can execute directly (e.g. using Console.WriteLine) and the version of .NET you're using?

Comment: Are you sure Company.Project is the correct namespace? Node is a very common class name. Maybe you have a Company.Project.Controls.Node class as well? Just a tought

Comment: Of course "Node" is just for StackOverflow and demonstration purposes. In my real project the namespace and class names look differently.

Comment: Can't reproduce either. Displays correct ToString in both cases here

Comment: What does n.GetType().FullName say? (for both cases)

Comment: GetType().FullName returns "Company.Project.Node" in either case.
The problem is 100% reproducable. However I cannot reproduce it in linqpad either with a simplified example... although the interesting bits and pieces are the same. Only the population of the _nodes list is lacking here - and some real world content.

Comment: What happens if you put the OrderBy at the end (after SelectMany)?  I don't have .net 4.5.5, just 4.5.1.  I'm also not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `.Select(x => new { ... })` in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce, this is the test always passing.

Is it passing in your compiler also? Could you check it with your workstation?

Or are we missing something here, different than yours?

```
public class Node
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("This is the Node.ToString() method!");
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var unsortedNodes = new List<Node>()
    {
        new Node { Group = "A", SequenceNumber = 1 },
        new Node { Group = "A", SequenceNumber = 2 },
        new Node { Group = "A", SequenceNumber = 3 },
        new Node { Group = "B", SequenceNumber = 11 },
        new Node { Group = "B", SequenceNumber = 12 },
        new Node { Group = "C", SequenceNumber = 20 },
    };

    var query = unsortedNodes.OrderBy(n => n.Group).GroupBy(n => n.Group).SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(n => n.SequenceNumber));
    var _nodes = query.ToList();
    Assert.IsTrue(_nodes.ToList().All(n => n.ToString() == "This is the Node.ToString() method!"));
}
```